How to make facet search by multiple nested fields in Elasticsearch Java API Client?
There are my example documents.
"id" : "1",
"title" : "test",
"description" : "test",
"price" : 100.0,
"category_id" : "1",
"characteristics" : [
  {
    "characteristic_id" : "1",
    "text_value" : "red"
  },
  {
    "characteristic_id" : "2",
    "numeric_value" : 15
  },
  {
    "characteristic_id" : "3",
    "numeric_value" : 20
  }
]

"id" : "2",
"title" : "test",
"description" : "test",
"price" : 200.0,
"category_id" : "1",
"characteristics" : [
  {
    "characteristic_id" : "1",
    "text_value" : "blue"
  },
  {
    "characteristic_id" : "2",
    "numeric_value" : 10
  },
  {
    "characteristic_id" : "3",
    "numeric_value" : 5
  }
]

And a query to my index must be like this. How can i write this using new Java Api Client for Elasticsearch?
GET product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "characteristics",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "characteristics.characteristic_id": 1
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "characteristics.text_value": "blue"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "characteristics",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "characteristics.characteristic_id": 3
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "characteristics.numeric_value": {
                        "gte": 1,
                        "lte": 7
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "category_id": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gt": 10.0,
              "lt": 500.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {          
          "match": {
            "title": "te"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

There is very little information in the official documentation. Should I even use this API if there is no normal documentation for it and write all the requests manually?

I have rolled back your edit. If you managed to solve your own problem, then post an Answer, do not add the solution to your Question.

sorry, but i cant, even when i use code block, it writes "Too long by N characters" @Mark Rotteveel

That generally means that you have provide only code, and no explanation of your solution.

nope, still cant add a comment with code (i typed a lot of text before code block).
nah, just leave a link to my solution in other forum @Mark Rotteveel

You should not post a comment with code, you should post an answer, below in the "Your Answer" section.

sorry for my stupidity @Mark Rotteveel

Java code
        List<Query> filters = new ArrayList<>();

        if(requestPayload.getPriceTo() != 0) {
            filters.add(RangeQuery.of(r -> r
                            .field("price")
                            .gte(JsonData.of(requestPayload.getPriceFrom()))
                            .lte(JsonData.of(requestPayload.getPriceTo())))
                    ._toQuery());
        }

        if(requestPayload.getCategoryId() != null) {
            filters.add(TermQuery.of(t -> t
                    .field("category_id")
                    .value(requestPayload.getCategoryId()))
                    ._toQuery());
        }

        List<RangeQuery> rangeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(var category : requestPayload.getFilters().getNumericValues()) {
            for (var numericValue : category.getValues()) {
                if (numericValue.getFrom() != null && numericValue.getTo() != null) {
                    rangeList.add(RangeQuery.of(r -> r
                            .field("characteristics.numeric_value")
                            .gte(JsonData.of(numericValue.getFrom()))
                            .lte(JsonData.of(numericValue.getTo()))));
                }
            }

            filters.add(NestedQuery.of(n -> n
                    .path("characteristics")
                    .query(q -> q
                            .bool(b -> {
                                b.must(m -> m
                                        .term(t -> t
                                                .field("characteristics.characteristic_id")
                                                .value(category.getCharacteristicId())));

                                for (RangeQuery rangeQuery : rangeList)
                                    b.should(s -> s.range(rangeQuery));

                                b.minimumShouldMatch("1");
                                return b;
                            })
                    ))._toQuery());
        }

        for(var category : requestPayload.getFilters().getTextValues()) {

            List<FieldValue> textValuesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(var textValue : category.getValues()) {
                textValuesList.add(FieldValue.of(textValue));
            }

            TermsQueryField textValues = TermsQueryField.of(tf -> tf.value(textValuesList));
            if(!textValuesList.isEmpty()) {
                filters.add(NestedQuery.of(n -> n
                                .path("characteristics")
                                .query(q -> q
                                        .bool(b -> b
                                                .must(m -> m
                                                        .term(t -> t
                                                                .field("characteristics.characteristic_id")
                                                                .value(category.getCharacteristicId())))
                                                .must(m -> m
                                                        .terms(t -> t
                                                                .field("characteristics.text_value")
                                                                .terms(textValues))))))
                        ._toQuery());
            }
        }

        BoolQuery boolQuery = BoolQuery.of(b -> b
                .filter(filters)
                .should(s -> s
                        .match(m -> m
                                .field("title")
                                .query(requestPayload.getText()))));

        SearchResponse<ProductDocument> response = esClient.search(s -> s
                        .index("product")
                        .query(q -> q.bool(boolQuery)),
                ProductDocument.class);

        List<Hit<ProductDocument>> hits = response.hits().hits();
        for (Hit<ProductDocument> hit: hits) {
            System.out.println(hit.source());
        }

Json query
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
      
      "should": {
        "match": { "title": { "query": "te" } }
      },
      
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": { "price": { "gte": 1.0, "lte": 100.0 } }
        },

        {
          "term": { "category_id": "1" }
        },
        
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "characteristics",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                      { "term": { "characteristics.characteristic_id": "1" } },
                      { "terms": { "characteristics.text_value": ["red", "blue"] } }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "characteristics",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                      { "term": { "characteristics.characteristic_id": "4" } },
                      { "terms": { "characteristics.text_value": ["yes"] } }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "characteristics",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                      { "term": { "characteristics.characteristic_id": "2" } }
                ],
                "should": [
                      { "range": { "characteristics.numeric_value": { "gte": 1, "lte": 20 } } },
                      { "range": { "characteristics.numeric_value": { "gte": 21, "lte": 30 } } }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
        
      ] 
    }
  }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
